# How to connect to MS SQL Server using ODBC and DBI in R

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I'm having difficulty making a connection to my MS SQL Server from R.

I believe I'm using the right driver, I checked what drivers I had listed and picked the same one that I'm using in DBeaver for the connection to the same database:

```
odbcListDrivers() %>% filter(name %like% "SQL Server" & !name %like% "Teradata")
```

[image]

My connection string looks as follow:

```
db_conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       Driver   = "SQL Server",
                       Server   = "Server_address",
                       Database = "Database_Name",
                       UID      = "myName",
                       PWD      = "myPWd",
                       Trusted_Connection = "True",
                       Port     = 1433,
                       ApplicationIntent = "ReadOnly"
                       )
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 01S00: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The target database ('Database_Name') is in an availability group and is currently accessible for connections when the application intent is set to read only. For more information about application intent, see SQL Server Books Online.  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
```

I can connect to the same database using DBeaver and have specified the the connection has applicationIntent = readonly

[image]

Is there some other connection string property I need to include to make a connection?

Comment: I know the names tend to be case-insensitive, have you tried with `"readonly"` (lower-case)?

Comment: Can you try changing the `Trusted_Connection = "True"` to `Trusted_Connection = "Yes"`

Comment: First blush: did you update the text string above to include the server address and not "Server_address" and the actual database name instead of "Database_Name."

Comment: @akrun thanks for the suggestion, I tried this and no joy

Comment: @r2evans thanks also, I tried all permutations of upper and lower and no joy either

Comment: @JeffParker, thanks Jeff, I was sloppy with my phrasing. My database name is Server1234.xx.yy.company.com, this is what I tried

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I was using the correct connection string properties but the server was running in cluster mode and therefore I needed to append 'CLS' to my database name.

My final connection string looks as follows:

```
db_conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
  Driver = "SQL Server",
  Server = "SomeDBcls.xx.yy.zz.com",
  Database = "NameOfSchema",
  UID = "TheGoat",
  PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
  Trusted_Connection = "Yes",
  Port = 1433,
  applicationIntent = "readonly"
)
```

Comment: This sounds like a DNS (name-server) difference, is that right?